# Cómo validar si una frase String tiene exactamente los mismos caracteres que otra frase?

Tags: java, string

Tengo que comprar si estoy hablando de la misma persona en ambas variables pero en una viene primero con los apellidos y después los nombres y en la otra vienen los nombres y después los apellidos.

La manera en que se me ocurre poder validar esto es que ambas oraciones tienen exactamente los mismos caracteres y la misma cantidad de ellos, pero cómo hago eso?

```
String var1 = "Mauricio de Jesús Montes de la Oca";
String var2 = "Montes de la Oca Mauricio de Jesús";
//imprime true

String var1 = "Rodrigo Hernández";
String var2 = "Hernández Rodrigo";
//imprime true

String var1 = "Rodolfo Godínez Narrado";
String var2 = "Godínez Rodolfo";
//imprime false

String var1 = "María Magdalena Romero";
String var2 = "Romero María Magdalena";
//imprime true
```

Cómo valido que ambas son iguales? O al menos que cumplen con el requerimiento de tener exactamente los mismos caracteres y el mismo número de palabras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean iguales = false;
String nombre1 = ...
String nombre2 = ...
String[] arr1 = nombre1.toLowerCase().split(" ");
String[] arr2 = nombre2.toLowerCase().split(" ");

Arrays.sort(arr1);
Arrays.sort(arr2);

if(arr1.length == arr2.length)
{
   String n1 = "";
   String n2 = "";

   for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
   {
      n1 += arr1[i];
      n2 += arr2[i];
   }

   if(n1.equals(n2))
   {
      iguales = true;
   }
}

if(iguales)
   //imprime nombres iguales
else
   //imprime nombres no iguales
```

Lo que se hace aquí es mediante la **función split** separar ambos nombres por sus espacios y las palabras que se obtienen se guardan en un arreglo. Posteriormente se ordenan ambos arreglos, y se pregunta si el tamaño de ambos son iguales, de serlo pues se recorren los arreglos y en las **variables n1** y **n2** se van concatenado cada elemento de **arr1** y **arr2** respectivamente, después que se sale del **ciclo for** se pregunta si **n1** es igual a **n2**, de serlo la **variable igual** toma el valor de **true**, posteriormente se pregunta si la **variable igual** es **true**, de serlo se imprime que los nombres son iguales de no serlo se imprime que no son iguales.

Comment: Cambié el n1==n2 por n1.equals(n2) sino no funcionaba. Podrías editarla para ponerla como buena? muchas gracias

Comment: @user2930137, ok, y gracias

Comment: @user2930137, ya está arreglado

Comment: Ya la puse como buena, igual le falta un paréntesis en el if del equals, se lo quise editar pero no me dejó. Gracias por tu aporte, Japv. Saludos

Comment: @user2930137, ok, gracias a ti